# NoReverseMatch at / in Django How to pass url

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

```
<a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'tasks' %}">Tasks</a>
```

When I'm using this template tag I get an error no ReverseMatch.

but ,

```
<a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/tasks">Tasks</a>
```

When I'm doing this I get no error.

Can someone explain me?

**urls.py of the project**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('tracker.urls')),
    path('tasks/', include('tasks.urls')),
]
```

**urls.py of the tasks app**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.tasklist, name="tasklist"),
]
```

**views.py of the tasks app**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def tasklist(request):
    return render(request, 'tasks/task_list.html')
```

Comment: Your url name is `tasklist` not `tasks`. Hence you should be writing `{% url 'tasklist' %}`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice that.